# Sending value with transaction using Metamask and Browser-Solidity

Tags: transactions, blockchain, dapp-development, remix, metamask

Using browser-solidity in combination with metamask I am testing a new contract on testnet https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xc03db39c18b6056f8c3a3a5495a1e11f3ff8885a but when trying to call refillFunds() method:

```
/* Refill SC funds to feed faucet requests */
function refillFunds() payable returns (uint256) {
    calledRefillFunds(msg.sender, timestamp(), msg.value); // Log

    return 1;
}
```

I got this screen to perform a transaction

[image]

but there is no option (or I cannot find where it is) to transfer 1 ether for example. The only option seems to be to transfer 0 ethers and pay the fees.

Any reason why I cannot send non-zero value with metamask interface in this transaction? Thx!

Comment: where is the screen?

Comment: Coming right up ... sorry

Comment: what is the account balance ?

Comment: It's on the screenshot: 3.952 ethers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Browser Solidity, there is a tab where you can set the parameters to use when sending a transaction
[image]

Comment: Thx! It works like a dream!

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this within Metamask?

Comment: Choose "Injected Web3".

Comment: answer appears to be obsolete already. the current manifestation of browser-solidity is at remix.ethereum.org and there is no such tab.

Comment: ignore my comment, it's there under the Run tab. it was just confusing because I though that form was only for contract creation.